# Fast and simple and light reports system for .NET (asp mvc)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting, firebird

Does there exist a fast and light reporting system for projects in Visual Studio for projects in asp .net mvc? Crystal reports is too big and "heavy" and not a good choice for 200+ users who create a PDF report at once.
Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 2):

I like FastReport. But I just know the Delphi-Version and can't say how mature the .Net-Version is.
The Delphi-version is lightweight, easy to use but with it's scripting-possibilities very powerful.
So I think even the .Net-version should be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [List Label](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/report-generator-List-Label) (from combit), too! It has a different approach, a very good designer and direct vendor support. Distribution files are "lightweight" compared to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting services is free if you have an sql server license and if you run the reporting services server on the same db server.  I consider it pretty lightweight and easy to use.

Comment: I am using Firebird database, so shortly: at this time for every report need create DataSet, than in runtime load data from DB to DataTable and add this DataTable to DataSet. After all of this I create reports with data...

Answer (score 0):

Try the [ItextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) or the [nuget package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/iTextSharp)
We used it's and it was fine!

Comment: iTextSharp is cool, but you have to release all of your code as open source, or pay a license fee, so it's not free (I know you didn't say it was).

Answer (score 0):

DevXpress XtraReports allows you to design reports with a good designer then you use them as normal C# classes. I like it very much, you can create reports and export them to pdf file or stream on the server even with no UI at all then you can download the pdf from mvc or store it somewhere. I use it as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog which details about using Active Reports to create reports in a MVC  application. You can go through the blog [here](http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2011/11/using-active-reports-in-mvc-3.html).

Active Reports is a very flexible and easy to use reporting tool,it is supported on Win Forms, Asp.net, SilverLight and supports data sources like Sql Server, My Sql, XML, Oledb etc.